# How to provide <hr> after every item template in <asp:DataList> in vb.net?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I want to provide `<HR>` after every span generated by Item Template in `<asp:DataList>`.

**Here is my code:**

```
<asp:dataList>
 <HeaderTemplate> </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate> </ItemTemplate>     
 <FooterTemplate> </FooterTemplate>
</asp:dataList>
```

**Representation:**

```
<dataList>
//header
<span>...</span>
//I want to provide <hr> here
<span>...</span>
//I want to provide <hr> here
<span>...</span>
//I want to provide <hr> here
<span>...</span>
//footer
</dataList>
```

How can I provide `<HR>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataList does not provide the level of markup control that you require. To achieve this you need to switch to Repeater.

Repeater does not render any matkup on its own, and leaves it to user to output everything. So you will need to take care of all these spans, header and footer, but in return you have control over all markup being output.

Your Repeater setup will look like that:

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <span>
        What you would put in DataList header
        </span>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span>
        What you would put in DataList item
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <span>
        What you would put in DataList footer
        </span>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Notice that all markup rendered by DataList is now specified explicitly. But also note that `<hr/>` won't go into any span anymore.

Comment: it provide HR in SPAN. Like this <span><HR></span>. I just want <HR> without <SPAN>

Comment: @NanjiMange, oh, i see. Will remove this answer then. But first, a question. Is DataList a hard requirement for you? If you need more control over markup you maybe need a repeater instead

Comment: I don't want to change the existing functionality. I can user repeater if there is no possibilities.

Comment: @NanjiMange, completely revisited answer to show how you can use repeater here